# Numpy matrix subtraction over each column of another matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I know in numpy if you have a matrix **A** and I subtract a vector **v** by performing **A - v**, **v** will be broadcasted so that **v** becomes the same dimension as **A** and an elementwise subtraction will be performed.

I was wondering if I had to perform the above operation many times with the same **A** but with different **v**, would I be able to do it using vectorization.

A naive implementation would be as follow

```
def foo(A, V):
   """
   @params: A, V
   A - an n by m matrix
   V - a list of n by 1 column vectors
   @returns: result
   """

   result = []
   for v in V:
      result.append(A-v)
   return result
```

I know that I could pass in **V** as a n by p matrix where each column represents a **v**. However, I couldn't think of any way of describing the above operation in terms of linear algebra

For example if

```
 A = [[1 2 3], 
      [1 2 3]]

 V = [[1 4], 
      [1 4]]
```

the output should be two matrices

```
[
  [[0 1 2], 
  [0,1,2]], 

  [[-3 -2 -1], 
  [-3 -2, -1]]
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to vectorize this fully, but depending on how much performance boost you need a list comprehension might get you as far as you need: `result = [A - v for v in V]`

Comment: So yo want `[A-v[0], A-v[0]-v[1],...]`?  `A-np.cumsum(v, axis=1)` might do it.

Comment: If **V** contained a bunch of column vectors stacked horizontally, then I would want [A - V[:0], A-V[:1], ...]. Note it is important that the broadcasting occurs for each column vector. My final output should be a list or collection of matrices

Comment: What's `A` shape?  `v` and `result` shape to be clear?  We may need a small worked example.

Comment: **A** is an **n** by **m** matrix, and you could think of **V** as a **n** by **p** matrix

Comment: `V - a list of n by 1 column vectors` - can you give a minimal example of `V`? If `A = np.zeros((4,3)) + [1,2,3]` , `V` could be ... `[np.ones(4),np.ones(4)*2,np.ones(4)*3]`???

Comment: And the result, (p,n,m)?

Comment: That is correct. See the added example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = np.zeros((4,3)) + [1,2,3]
V = [np.ones(3),np.ones(3)*2,np.ones(3)*3]
```

Your desired is

```
>>> a-V[0]
array([[0., 1., 2.],
       [0., 1., 2.],
       [0., 1., 2.],
       [0., 1., 2.]])
>>> a-V[1] 
array([[-1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.]])
>>> a-V[2]
array([[-2., -1.,  0.],
       [-2., -1.,  0.],
       [-2., -1.,  0.],
       [-2., -1.,  0.]])
```

Stack the vectors in V then add a dimension to subtract.

```
>>> W = np.vstack(V)
>>> a - W[:,None,:]
array([[[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  2.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  2.]],

       [[-1.,  0.,  1.],
        [-1.,  0.,  1.],
        [-1.,  0.,  1.],
        [-1.,  0.,  1.]],

       [[-2., -1.,  0.],
        [-2., -1.,  0.],
        [-2., -1.,  0.],
        [-2., -1.,  0.]]])
```

---

Try it again adjusting for `(n,m)` is `(4,3)`

```
a = np.zeros((4,3)) + [1,2,3]       # (n.m) = (4,3)
V = [np.ones(4),np.ones(4)*2,np.ones(4)*3]  # three (nx1) vectors
W = np.vstack(V)

>>> a.shape
(4, 3)
>>> W.shape
(3, 4)
>>> Z = a - W[...,None] 
>>> Z[0]
array([[0., 1., 2.],
       [0., 1., 2.],
       [0., 1., 2.],
       [0., 1., 2.]])
>>> Z[1]
array([[-1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.],
       [-1.,  0.,  1.]])
>>> Z[2]
array([[-2., -1.,  0.],
       [-2., -1.,  0.],
       [-2., -1.,  0.],
       [-2., -1.,  0.]])
>>> Z.shape             
(3, 4, 3)
```

Comment: I might have gotten the `m` and `n` mixed up.

Comment: Your code `V = [np.ones(3),np.ones(3)*2,np.ones(3)*3]` is a list of row vectors, I need a list of column vectors. For example if 
`
A = [[1 2 3],
       [1 2 3]]
v = [[1 4],
      [1 4]] `
the output should be two matrices
`[ [[0 1 2], [[0,1,2],
[-3 -2 -1]], [-3 -2, -1]]]`

Comment: @coderhk See if the edit is what you were after.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that if I take the transpose of my **V** vector and then apply your algorithm it will produce the desired result. Nonetheless, it works thanks to you! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
In [104]:  A = [[1, 2, 3],
     ...:       [1, 2, 3]]
     ...: 
     ...:  V = [[1, 4],
     ...:       [1, 4]]
In [105]: A=np.array(A);V=np.array(V)
In [106]: A              # (n,m)
Out[106]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
In [107]: V               # (n,p)
Out[107]: 
array([[1, 4],
       [1, 4]])
```

The iterative subtraction; `[0]` used to make the array (2,1) (which broadcasts with (2,3) `A`:

```
In [108]: [A-V[:,[0]], A-V[:,[1]]]
Out[108]: 
[array([[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]]),
 array([[-3, -2, -1],
        [-3, -2, -1]])]
```

Lets try whole array broadcasting:

```
In [109]: A[None,:,:]-V[:,:,None]
Out[109]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [-3, -2, -1]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2],
        [-3, -2, -1]]])
```

Oops, wrong mix; try again, changing `V` to (p,n).  That would have been clearer is `V` wasn't (2,2):

```
In [110]: A[None,:,:]-V.T[:,:,None]
Out[110]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 0,  1,  2]],

       [[-3, -2, -1],
        [-3, -2, -1]]])
```

With (2,4) `V`:

```
In [112]: V1=np.hstack((V,V))
In [113]: V1.shape
Out[113]: (2, 4)
In [114]: (A[None,:,:]-V1.T[:,:,None]).shape
Out[114]: (4, 2, 3)
In [115]: (A-V1.T[:,:,None]).shape
Out[115]: (4, 2, 3)
```